# Error in file upload cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to upload file from android phone to webserver.
I am using ourcodeworld.Filebrowser.filePicker plugin to select/choose the file.
I can select the file but it is not uploading

Here is the code i have written so far.

```
 function choose(){
    window.OurCodeWorld.Filebrowser.filePicker.single({
    success: function(data){
        if(!data.length){
            alert('No file selected');
            return;
        }
    alert(data);
    var fileURI = data;

            servers = 'http://www.sample.com/mobile_app/upload.php';

           var server = servers;

         if (server) {
             var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="fileUpload";
             options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
             options.mimeType = "text/plain";
            options.chunkedMode = false;
              options.headers = {
               Connection: "close"
            };
              var params = new Object();
             params.uid = uid;
              options.params = params;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
             ft.upload(fileURI, server, win, fail, options);
              ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
             if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
         var perc = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);

                 alert(perc);
                  $("#prog2").show();
                 document.getElementById('prog2').innerHTML ='<h4>Uploading :'+perc+'%</h4>';
            } else {
                    if(statusDom.innerHTML == "") {
                    statusDom.innerHTML = "Loading";
            } else {
                    statusDom.innerHTML += ".";
            }
        }
    };
    }
        },
    error: function(err){
         alert(err);
    }

     });
    }
```

Data is coming till         `alert(data);` and i can also confirm code is working till here          `if (server) {`.

As per my debugging from this line it is not showing anything `var options = new FileUploadOptions();`

i can confirm cordova.js is loading properly.

Any advise what am i doing wrong?

I am testing it on emulator.

**Edit :**  File is returning like this from ourcodeworld plugin.

```
// ["file:///storage/emulated/0/360/security/file.txt"]
```

**Edit2 :** 
I am using this plugin https://github.com/ourcodeworld/cordova-ourcodeworld-filebrowser

and in the sample code i can see this.

```
// Array with filepaths
        // ["file:///storage/emulated/0/360/security/file.txt", "file:///storage/emulated/0/360/security/another-file.txt"]
```

So, it seems like plugin is returning array data. I think problem is here.

Comment: its not even getting into error callback?? Did you tried debugging in device so that you can get error in console trace?

Comment: If no file is selected then it is showing the alert. But it is not going to error call back.

Comment: Could be possible problem with fileURI. Could you plz try hardcoding a path and see it it works fine so that we can segregate the issue?

Comment: I put the filepath as hardcoded and i can say it proceed. However i need to debug more till php file but initially it started. It seems like earlier data is in array format. Any advise what to do now

Comment: All i can say for now it that the problem is with the file path since hardcoding works as u said. Would like u to investigate in the lines of file path and encoding the server URL

Comment: I have updated the question please have a look. It seems like problem is in array data use.

Comment: if it returns an array, then u may to fetch single value out of it and send it to file transfer plugin as the plugin wont accept array of paths